# "Would you?" or "Will you?"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, difference

I'm in the process of book-writing (mainly for fun; I don't think it's one I will ever publish, but who knows), and a good friend of mine is proof-reading it for me. It's more like me making her do it because I feel like I need the feedback, both about the story and the sentence structure (grammar and punctuation are taken care of by Grammarly and Word).

Long story short, she had pointed out something she thinks is a mistake, but when we got chatting about it both her and I have become confused. We simply couldn't make out whether it was correct or not, or whether there is even a mistake.

**The question:**

A child is getting ready to go out and his mother asks him to put on nice trousers for the event, and she says, "Put on a normal shirt. And a pair of decent trousers while you are at it, **will you?**"

My friend said that in her opinion it should be **"would you?"**, but I just feel like there is no difference between the two. It's the way people talk; some people say the first, and some say the second. But here is my question to you fellow ELLs. Is there a difference, really? Is the first more demanding and the second more polite, or the other way around? Is one of these correct and the other incorrect? I'm really looking forward to receiving an answer, we both have been befuddled since the conversation regarding that phrase.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: **Would you?** is generally considered more polite and indirect than **will you?**. So a parent is more likely to say **will you?** to a child and **would you?** to a friend. Thus you might hear **Will you be going to the dance?** and **Would you be able to assist me?**

Comment: @RonaldSole Perfect, thanks! :)